# .active class via PHP

Tags: php, function, html-lists

I created this PHP function:

```
function active_class($page){
    global $pagebase;

    if($pagebase == $page){
        return "active";
    }
    elseif($pagebase == null){
        $page = "home";
        return "active";
    }
    else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

But when I use it with this list:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="<?php echo active_class("home"); ?>"><a href="http://example.com/home">Home</a></li>
              <li class="<?php echo active_class("about"); ?>"><a href="http://example.com/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

It shows the active class on both at `http://example.com` without the /home or /about. I am looking for a way to fix this. Any ideas?

`$pagebase` is just the `$_GET['page']`. It is the /home or /about for each page.

Comment: `$page == "home";` for one thing, there's one `=` too many here, and is probably the root of this problem and is a typo. Edit: Oh, so it's going to be an "edit on the fly" post.

Comment: looks like a basic typo issue?

Comment: Changed the typo,

Comment: $pagebase always null, therefore active?

Comment: $pagebase is null if there if there is nothing after the trailing /

Comment: Whatever is after the / such as "/home" will turn $pagebase into it. so "/home" means $pagebase = home;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `$pagebase` is null, for it to make just the home tab active, you have to add in - `$page == "home"` - condition so that the null state is just for the home tab and only returns active once.

**Try:**

```
function active_class($page){
    global $pagebase;

    if($pagebase == $page){
        return "active";
    }
    elseif($pagebase == null && $page == "home" ){
        $page = "home";
        return "active";
    }
    else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Another alternative:**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="<?php echo ($pagebase=="home"?"active":""); ?>"><a href="http://example.com/home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="<?php echo ($pagebase=="about"?"active":""); ?>"><a href="http://example.com/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="<?php echo ($pagebase == 'home')?'active':'';; ?>"><a href="http://example.com/home">Home</a></li>
```

I am sure it will work like this way.

Answer (score 0):

After looking back at my code, I figured that I can just change `$pagebase` to equal home if it is null (No `$_GET['page']`. This would allow me to use my code meanwhile not using the elseif. Thank you for the replies.